# @index issue inside the {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

When we are working with `{{#each}}` helper we are facing following issue.

```
JSON: {arr1 : ["a","v"],arr2 : ["c","d"]}

Template:
{{#each arr1}}
{{../arr2.[0]}}
{{/each}}
```

Above code is working fine. But when we use `@index` insteated of static index number in the arr2 its not working. we couldn't understand why `@index` value is not placed.

For Example (Not working),

```
Template:1
{{#each arr1}}
{{../arr2.[@index]}}
{{/each}}

Template:2
{{#each arr1}}
{{../arr2.[index]}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `{{@index}}` not just `@index`.